# adding configuration to a solution after creating it so that it builds via MSbuild

Tags: configuration, build, msbuild, solution

I created a solution based of the different csproj files using solution maker tool. This tool creates a master solution but does not add configurations to the projects or the solution, the way Visual Studio adds configuration settings to the solution file when it builds it. I tried to build it using MSbuild new.sln command from the Developer Command prompt for VS2013. I even tried using the command by giving configuration options but it still doesn't work. The solution builds without actually building any output when triggered by MSbuild unless built in Visual Studio first. Is there a way for MSbuild or another way to add the configuration settings to the solution file so it can actually build it?

Answer (score 0):

I used devenv to build the solution instead and it worked.